# User signup source in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm trying to setup a cloud function that takes care of extraneous user data (to be stored in Firestore) for a user on new signup. However, I have different kinds of users. The user is given a `userLevel` depending on where they signed up from. For example, a user can be considered a Power User if they signed up via the website, whereas if they signed up via the app they'd be a Regular User.

I tried finding in the docs but user info context does not provide a "source" for the registration -- the closest thing being the type of registration used i.e. Google, Facebook, Email etc.

How can I accurately set user info in Firestore based on which platform the user signed up from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any built-in way to determine from what platform the user signed up. But even if there was, it could easily be spoofed. Any user can sign up from any platform with the providers you've enabled.

The simplest way to work around the feature (still with the caveat about it being spoofable) would be to write a node to the database from the app right after the user registered. Use that to trigger your Cloud Function, and work from there.